# jquery Plugin define selector in this case "document"

Tags: jquery, plugins

Ok, I have been having a VERY hard time figuring this out. I guess I'm still new when it comes to creating jQuery plugins. I am going to post the entire code in a JSFiddle but here is the jist of the problem. My plugin right now uses the $.fn.extend method to allow users to chose a selector like: `$(document).BGP({/*options*/});` ---this is fine except the BGP function will ONLY work with the "document" therefore I would like to remove the selector option and program this into the plugin. So that the user can call like: $.BGP({/*options*/});

I am lost on how to do this!!! I have tried many different things and nothing works.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
            BGP: function (options) {
                    //Set the default
                    var defaults = {
                            backgroundStretch: "",
                            backImage: "",
                            midImage: "",
                            foreImage: ""...and much more
```

Here is the JS fiddle----this is a working example with the "document" selector.

Also I have some minified code at the top of the JS....you can ignore that. My code starts about halfway down.

My call for the function is at the bottom of the JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/mgunnels/3Z2sK/6/

Comment: If it won't work on any given jquery object, why have it called on a jquery object?  Maybe it should just be called directly `$.BGP(`?

Comment: James---that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. If you can help me do that....that would be great!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a "static" plugin, all you need to do is assign your function directly to the `jQuery` object:

```
(function($) {
    $.BGP = function(arg1) { ... };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$.BGP("foo");
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/n8ea4/

Additionally, you don't need the `.each` loop at all since there can only be one `document`.

Comment: Andrew can you show me on the JS fiddle. The link above is a working example with the call to the $(document)....I have tried the above suggested but it did not work for me. I must have done something wrong.

Comment: thanks, so much. I'm an idiot I was breaking the code by not removing the closing brackets! Thanks for your help and I'll remove the .each loop.